# Что лучше коррелированный подзапрос или INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Есть таблица check и corp

Запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT 
    check.contr_date
    check.bank_account
    ... (Ещё 6 полей из check) 
    (TRIM(corp.name1) || TRIM (corp.name2) || TRIM(corp.name2) AS corp_name
FROM
    check
    INNER JOIN corp USING(id_corp)
```

Как видно таблица corp нужна только чтобы получить названия корпорации. Это можно сделать и подзапросом. Вопрос в том что будет быстрее? Есть ли способ это как-то замерить?

Comment: Если запрос именно такой - без WHERE, то 99% за то, что вариант с JOIN будет как минимум не медленнее варианта с коррелированным подзапросом. *Есть ли способ это как-то замерить?* [SET EXPLAIN statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statements-set-explain-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Какую СУБД вы используете?

Если работаете с MySQL\Maria DB, то перед вашим запросом можно указать ключевое слово 'explain'
В таблице вывода помимо значений из столбцов будут содержаться параметры, указывающие на скорость выполнения запроса.
Можно сравнить вариант с  join и с подзапросом.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/211022/)

Comment: Используется informix

Comment: К сожалению, не работала с Informix. Нужно поискать в сторону аналогов explain для данной субд.  Вот пример -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HKmNIp--F0